# How to fix 'Invalid bean definition with name requestMappingHandlerAdapter' error in Spring Boot Webflux app with Spring Boot Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, spring-webflux

I would like to use a spring security with spring boot webflux, but I get a following error when I start the application:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=requestMappingHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]] for bean 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter': There is already [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.web.reactive.config.DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration; factoryMethodName=requestMappingHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in org.springframework.web.reactive.config.DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration] bound.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:274) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
```

gradle dependencies are:

- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.1.3.RELEASE
- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.1.3.RELEASE

Security config contains @EnableWebFluxSecurity and a minimal userDetailsService and a SecurityWebFilterChain bean definition.

```
    @Bean
    fun userDetailsService(): MapReactiveUserDetailsService {
        val user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user")
                .password("user")
                .roles("USER")
                .build()
        return MapReactiveUserDetailsService(user)
    }

    @Bean
    fun springSecurityFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        http
                .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic().and()
                .formLogin()
        return http.build()
    }
```

It seems to me that spring-boot-starter-webflux is not compatible with spring-boot-starter-security. 
I have tried spring-boot-starter-security-reactive library also, but it has only 2.0.0.M5 version. Is there any way to use spring-boot-starter-webflux with spring-boot-starter-security?

Comment: If anyone is getting this error while using @SpringBootTest , you can disable MVC via SpringBootTest(properties = "spring.main.web-application-type=reactive")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you post your configuration beans? 
Do you have both

> @EnableWebflux

and

> @EnableWebMvc

?

Do you rely on overriding beans on purpose?
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#bean-overriding

Regards,
Alex

Comment: I have solved it, there were a dependency to spring-boot-starter-tomcat in class path in one module what I used

Answer (score 3):

Encountered this today, and it happened due to this dependency
`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket`

Apparently, this starter package for websocket depends on
`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web`

After I removed it, everything comes back to normal.

Comment: Took me hours before I finally found this answer. Thanks, I wish the errors were more obvious that `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-webflux` contradict each other in setup