# bean with that name has already been defined in org.springframework.web.reactive.config.DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a Spring Cloud Gateway project with the following project dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix:2.2.10.RELEASE'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.5'
    implementation 'com.netflix.eureka:eureka-core'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-vault-config'
    implementation 'com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:3.1.1'
    implementation 'commons-validator:commons-validator:1.7'
    implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.4.0-b180830.0359'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine'
    implementation 'com.auth0:jwks-rsa:0.21.2'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.42.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-context-support:5.3.23'
    implementation 'net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:7.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap:3.1.4'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'    
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.0'
}
```

When I start the project I get error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in org.springframework.web.reactive.config.DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Looks like there are sub 2 dependencies into dependencies. Do you know how I can fix this without overriding?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like both Spring MVC and Spring WebFlux dependencies coming into the classpath by adding the dependencies you mentioned, and because of that below error is coming at startup.

```
The bean 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in org.springframework.web.reactive.config.DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration and overriding is disabled.
```

Ideally, you should use either Spring MVC or Spring WebFlux. Please refer below links. I hope you will get the fix.

- [APPLICATION FAILED TO START due to same bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57472586/application-failed-to-start-due-to-same-bean)
- [How to fix 'Invalid bean definition with name requestMappingHandlerAdapter' error in Spring Boot Webflux app with Spring Boot Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55939970/how-to-fix-invalid-bean-definition-with-name-requestmappinghandleradapter-erro)
- [SpringWebFlux Error with @EnableWebFlux annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069614/springwebflux-error-with-enablewebflux-annotation)